# Can't find variable: IDBIndex on firebase/react native(expo)

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am developing a RN app in Expo with firebase as backend. So far, the app only uses firebase auth and firestore and for whatever reason, I randomly started getting the error of `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: IDBIndex`. I adjusted my firebase config to suit the v9 standards instead of using the `compat` package. I ensured my app was not using Google Analytics. I have also downgraded to firebase@9.1.0 which matches up with the expo documentation and this other similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67148613/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-idbindex-when-using-firebase-on-expo).
I have also git reverted into previous versions of the app (with earlier dependencies and code) when it was working but still got back the same error. When this occurred, I entirely reinstalled node and npm because I thought that was the only other possible reason this could be happening but that was to no avail as well (getting the same IDB error). I still think this is a firebase related issue, but I am pretty much all out of ideas as to what it could be.

Here is my firebase config:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";

import {
  FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
} from '@env';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default app;
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const firestore = getFirestore(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
    connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, "localhost", 8080);
}
```

Do let me know if you need to see more files or need to know more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other fixes mentioned in this thread are definitely all valid (I have seen other forum posts suggesting the firebase downgrade but in my case it did not work.)

I thought it could be helpful for me to confirm what fixed the problem in my case. The problem arose from when one of my team members used `npm` instead of `expo` (which defaults to `yarn`) to install a dependency. This caused syncing issues between the `yarn.lock` and `package-lock.json`. This alone wouldn't have caused much of an issue because a simple `yarn` or `yarn install <dependency>` would have solved the issue. However, this dependency happened to require pre-existing dependencies which were of a different version then the ones "expected" by my version of expo. How this `IDBIndex` error was triggered is still a mystery to me, but in the end all I had to do was remove all my lock files and `node_modules`, perform an `expo update`and finally do a `yarn` to reinstall all now-compatible packages.

If anyone stumbling across this answer can give a possible explanation as to why this fixed things, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are those "now compatible packages?"

Comment: Basically the numerous packages which were causing issues before (because they were different versions then what expo "wanted")

Answer (score 14):

*firebaser here*

There was a problem in our JavaScript SDKs, where Firebase Installation Services used a version of IDB that doesn't support ESM outside of browser environments. The issue has been fixed in [version 9.6.9](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_969_-_march_17_2022) of the JavaScript SDK, so be sure to update to that.

Answer (score 8):

I'm getting the same issue, looks like, it's breaking on `"firebase": "^9.6.8",` which was released a few days ago. Use `"firebase": "9.6.7",`

Comment: Still getting the same darn error! Got any other tips?

Comment: did you try the above version without caret? ```"firebase": "9.6.7"```

Comment: with caret it is working fine

Comment: I can confirm downgrading from 9.6.8 to 9.6.7 solved the issue for me too. Make sure that you only have that specific version specified as @JuniusL indicated it. 
If it does not solve it, delete you node_modules folder and reinstall everything with yarn or npm.

Comment: This worked for me, just make sure you just put "firebase": "9.6.7" with the carer (^)...

Comment: @JuniusL. Yup and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I've been getting the same issue, I've tried all the same things as you to no avail. I symbolicated the logs from firebase test lab and came up with this:

[Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYrS2.png)

Generally I have no idea how all of these libraries work together, but are you using typesense with firestore? I wonder if your stack trace calls out the same files, but I can't find any smoking gun here. I'll keep updating this thread if I find something. (I would have commented but I don't have the rep yet)

Update: Looks like my build just fixed itself somehow, even submitting builds from this weekend that would constantly crash. So truly I'm not sure what happened but it may be resolved

Comment: Hey Ewan, in my case I figured out that it was indeed a dependency error. How I found out was by removing node modules and yarn.lock and then reinstalling it all. When I did an `expo start` following this, expo started warning me about some dependencies being the wrong version. I did an `expo update` which sorted it out for me. Maybe you could try that too.

Comment: Do be careful about using `expo update` thou, make sure to git commit your project first before doing that command because it may break some things. In my case, the problematic dependencies consisted of `safe-area-context`,`gesture-handler`,`reanimated` and `@gorhom/bottom-sheet` amongst others. My stacktrace indicated something to do with `tslib`, which in the end was not helpful at all 

Comment: ```expo update``` didn't work for me

Comment: Hey @JuniusL. to be honest, I feel like this error message is definitely very vague and can happen for many different reasons. Try the downgrades suggested in the other answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, my solution was to downgrade the Firebase version from 9.6.8 to 8.2.3.

Here is a reference that could be helpful.

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/3066

Comment: The previous error went away, but only to replace by other different errors! Anything else you've tried? What would be the thing that cause this? Thanks

Comment: Pleas note that downgrading from v9 to v8 will cause some compatibility issues as v9 code is written differently then v8 firebase code. This could be what is causing your new set of errors @Onthewaytosuccess

Comment: @perrywinkle That got to be the reason for the other errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and after trying multiple different firebase versions, this is the one that fixed the error for me:

```
npm install firebase@9.4.1 --save
```

Here's where I found this: [Get Started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

Comment: Hey there Leena, what would be causing the error? the version that you've tried didn't work for me! Now having different annoying errors. What else have you tried? Thanks

Comment: The one before the latest one works. 9.6.7

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess I think it may have to do with certain dependency versions not being compatible with others. In my error message, it says the error was occurring in node_modules/react-native. That's why I tried to change the version numbers to see what worked!

Comment: @LeenaDomadia for me it's node_modules\tslib\tslib.js.  Does it tell anything to you?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess I haven't gotten that one. This is a bizarre error since it seems like everyone gets the same error message but located in different files in node_modules. Hard to pinpoint the exact reason for the error

Comment: @LeenaD. Now it works. It was due to a version mismatch of firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me (using yarn):

1. deleted node_modules
2. deleted yarn.lock
3. downgraded to firebase "9.6.7" `yarn add firebase@9.6.7`
4. downloaded packages using `yarn install`
5. made sure all my imports are from the correct firebase library. I am using expo, and I had imported both firebase and react-native-firebase, which was causing trouble. I deleted react-native-firebase for now until I eject if needed.
6. Fixed my imports. Now you import firebase like this `import firebase from "firebase/compat"`

Answer (score 0):

if you use firebase analytics, remove it

firebase version `"firebase": "9.6.7"`

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
// import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// export const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

export const firestore = getFirestore(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, I just downgraded firebase version and it worked.
you can use this code for downgrading:

```
npm install firebase@9.4.1 --save
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for Expo:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6253#issuecomment-1123923581

```js
// metro.config.js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```