# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: firebase . I can not connect the App to Firebase from Expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to create an App with a Database in which I will add several collections in Cloud Firestore.
but it is impossible, since the app was broken when I added the code to connect the app.

I've seen various solutions on Stack and GitHub, but after hours of testing, it doesn't work.

[bud search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ReferenceError:%20Can%27t%20find%20variable:%20firebase%20site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=APq-WBuBMLfAo-j06WqRUQDOzIBGo6rDgA:1650476137924&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj62aTflqP3AhV9hP0HHblIC2AQrQIoBHoECAgQBQ&biw=1183&bih=943&dpr=2)

[Firebase v9 modular - Can't find variable: IDBIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71389323/firebase-v9-modular-cant-find-variable-idbindex)

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8089

For now the Application is very simple, only two files are involved in Firebase and nothing works

I have changed the way to call Firebase in several ways:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
```

Currently the code I have is the following:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey:       "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain:   "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId:    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId:             "xxxxxxxxxxx"
}

export const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

file actions.js

```
import { firebaseApp } from "./firebase"
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const db = firebase.firestore(firebaseApp)

export const isUserLogged = () => {
  let isLogged = false
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=> {
    user !== null && (isLogged = true)
  })
  return isLogged
}
```

And the errors that the console shows me:

**

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_app.default.initializeApp')
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
```

**

How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing functions from the newer modular SDK, but then are tryign to call the older namespaced APIs. That won't work.

I recommend using the code samples from [getting started with Firebase Authentication on the web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start), [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) and the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

With the new modular syntax, you can build a function that returns a promise with first auth state with:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export const isUserLogged = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let unsubcribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      unsubcribe();
      resolve(user !== null)
    })
  });
}
```

---

If you want to stick to using the namespaced API, you can either import an older version of Firebase (e.g. the latest v8 release) or [use the compat path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat) for the new SDK, in the same upgrade guide I linked above.

Comment: Thanks @frankvanpuffelen  , I have added the code you provide me, and I still get the same error. The code is the one shown in a tutorial I'm following and it works fine for the teacher.
I do not know what else to do

Comment: Thanks @frankvanpuffelen , as my experience is limited, I have followed with the same code that I have, and I have resorted to a version ("7.9.0") of Firebase. This is showing me problems with AsyncStorage, but at the moment I don't know how to solve it