# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: IDBIndex

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to set up firebase in my react app and I am getting the following error
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: IDBIndex.

I have disabled analytics already. Has anyone seen this error?

This is my firebaseMethods.js file:

```
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "..."
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebase;
```

I am then calling
`const ref = firebase.firestone().collection("available_books");`

Comment: This is a known issue on some non-browser environments with the most recent release of the Firebase SDKs. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71414517/209103) to the question I linked for more info, and a link to the Github [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6042) where it's being tracked